# How to Downgrade from 7.1 to 7.0 in Mango Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I installed the windows phone 7 mango sdk in order to experiment with multitasking and some other mango-only features. I upgraded my project to 7.1 only to realize that there is not an update for the developer phone also. Since I need to test on the actual phone to prove things to my teacher, I need to downgrade to 7.0. I removed all Mango-only code, but now cannot downgrade the project.

**How can I manually downgrade the project to 7.0?**

I tried to create a new project and move over the code, but there is a lot of stuff that does not work correctly. I also tried setting some XML files to 7.0, but it does not build.

**What files are changed when upgrading?**

Comment: I did. But, when I downgrade, I am not sure which files I should revert because I did make some significant code changes after the upgrade. i.e. When I revert the csproj files to the version before the upgrade, they lose data for the new classes/changes made after.

Comment: if you did, then can't you just diff the whole project and you'd know for sure which files changed?

Comment: I'll look into that. I am still new to subversion so there are some things I do not know. Thanks. :)

Comment: As John mentioned, you should be able to use Subversion to diff & merge any changes you want to keep and revert the rest to the earlier revision. I've never used Subversion, but there are several tutorials available if you google it. Also, my favorite diff / merge tool is WinMerge (it's free).

Comment: I'll check out WinMerge. I was able to get it working proper after trying the SVN comparison, but still a nice tool to have available. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a blog from a Microsoft person:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimw/archive/2011/05/27/windows-phone-7-development-how-to-change-the-target-phone-version-back-to-v7-0-from-v7-1.aspx

It's going to involve hand editing your .csproj file with Notepad to change the TargetFrameworkProfile.

Once you've got the project open in Visual Studio, you'll have to deal with fixing any code that was actively using Mango features.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that our through comparison of code, but this definitely something to reference. Thanks for the help. :

Answer (score 3):

I found these steps a little more comprehensive. Steps 6 and 7 got me over the line.

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Switching-between-Windows-Phone-7-1-Mango-and-7-0-RTW-and-vice-versa